# Can we play the prompt to customer and record all conversations between customer, bot and agent at the same time in MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, azure-bot-service

When customer makes a call to Teams phone number, we want the call to be answered by MS teams Bot and play the prompt to customer. Secondly, we want to make invite to some MS Teams participant. At the same time, we want to record all the audio between customer, bot and participant.

As per MS documentation,  [play prompt API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/call-playprompt?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http,) works with service hosted media bot only(like [IVR Bot](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/StatelessSamples/SimpleIvrBot)), not with Application hosted media(like [Teams Recording Bot](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples/V1.0Samples/AksSamples(Deprecated)/teams-recording-bot)) which does the real time audio streams recording.

In my use case, I need both Play prompt APIs (Service hosted Media) and Teams Recording Bot to record the conversation in real time (Application hosted media).

Can anyone please suggest me a solution for this? Any help or feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The bot can be either app hosted media (local media) or service hosted media (remote media). Play Prompt is only supported by remote media, so that your bot won't be able to get real time media stream to record.

Currently, we don't allow bot to do convenience recording.

Comment: thank you for your response. I know that the same IVR bot can not be used for recording. But I am trying to invite the teams recording bot into the call conference of IVR bot. Is this possible using Invite API (Resource account with phone number) OR can we do it through join url? (Note: Since this is a call conference, I am not sure how to get the join URL because it is available only for MS Teams meeting).
Any feedback would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: there will be an API to allow bot to start recording leveraging Teams built-in recorder. But that will only support scheduled online meeting.